# How do I fix the bug whereby I don't get my bonus in Deus Ex 1

Tags: deus-ex

In Deus Ex, everytime I go in to see manderly, he says something like "here is your 1000 op bonus" but then afterwards, under skills I have the exact same number of skill points. Is this a common bug? how do I fix it

Comment: is he giving you a skill point bonus or a credit bonus?

Comment: I assumed they were all skill points

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manderly gives you a 1000 bonus in **credits.**

Verified here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/250533-deus-ex/faqs/10041

> Now go up and visit Manderly. His L/PW is on his secretary's desk, and you can
>   read his account or hack it on the secretary machine. Talk to her, and then go
>   into Manderly's office. 250 skill points. He'll give you 1000 credits, plus 250
>   if you rescued Hermann. And he'll know if you've been in the ladies' restroom!

Comment: He always yells at me for going to the ladies' restroom. I JUST CANT HELP IT!

Comment: I spill my drink!